# Running shell script with java on linux

Tags: java, linux, shell

I am moving my Runescape private server from Windows to Linux.
The server has a run.bat to start up.

```
@echo off
title Project Kingscape
java -cp bin;deps/poi.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar;deps/jython.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar;-server -XX:+AggressiveHeap -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=90 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=90 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+RelaxAccessControlCheck -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:CompileThreshold=1 -XX:ThreadStackSize=128 server.Server
pause
```

I converted this to the following .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -classpath bin:deps/poi.jar:deps/mysql.jar:deps/mina.jar:deps/slf4j.jar:deps/slf4j-nop.jar:deps/jython.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar:server.Server
read
```

I also have OpenJdk 7 installed.

When I try to run the run.sh file the terminal shows me the following:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -zero         to select the "zero" VM
    -jamvm        to select the "jamvm" VM
    -avian        to select the "avian" VM
    -dcevm        to select the "dcevm" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

I understand that probally my syntax is wrong, but to my regrets i do not have any linux knowledge.

Could someone help me to find you what is wrong?

Comment: Is it a typo that there is no space before `server.Server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a space between the classpath argument and the name of the main class:

```
java -classpath bin:deps/poi.jar:deps/mysql.jar:deps/mina.jar:deps/slf4j.jar: \
deps/slf4j-nop.jar:deps/jython.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar server.Server
                                                  ~ ~
```

The command should be exactly the same as the one on Windows except for using colons instead of semi-colons as path separators, so ideally:

```
java -cp bin:deps/poi.jar:deps/mysql.jar:deps/mina.jar:deps/slf4j.jar: \
deps/slf4j-nop.jar:deps/jython.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar \
-server -XX:+AggressiveHeap -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=90 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=90 \
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+RelaxAccessControlCheck -XX:+UseParallelGC \
-XX:CompileThreshold=1 -XX:ThreadStackSize=128 server.Server
```

Notice there should also be a space between the classpath and the `-server` argument in the initial command.

Comment: Thank, thank you alot. 2 days of searching and you just fixed it. I can accept your answer in 6 minutes.